# Questions related to semidirect-product of Klein four group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, semidirect-product

I have four questions related to Klein four group. and I know the answer two of them. ( the first two) and I want to know answer

1. Does $V_4$ has an automorphism of order 6?
2. What are the orders of automorphisms of $V_4$?
3. Can there be a non-commutative semi-direct product of $V_4\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}$
4. Can there be a non-commutative semi-direct product of $V_4\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}$?

The answer of the first two is well-know, $Aut(V_4)\simeq S_3$ so we can answer question number two from the answer of number one.
so I have trouble with the last two questions. and is there is a way I can use the answer of the first of two question in the answer. since all these questions is one part problem. 
any help appreciated.

Comment: So $3$ divides $|{\rm Aut}(V_4)|$ but $5$ does not. That  enables you to answer 3 and 4 immediately.

Comment: I still have the trouble connect your comment with part 3,4.. so now my question is this… What is the relation between $Aut(V_4)$ and  V4⋊ℤ/5ℤ . thanks your your hints.

Comment: To define a semidirect product $G \rtimes H$, you need to specify a homomorphism $\phi:H \to {\rm Aut}(G)$. (It is more accurate to write it as $G \rtimes_\phi H$.)